# 12.04 taking very long time while installing on VMware workstation 7.1.1

Tags: 12.04, installation, vmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition using VMware workstation 7.1.1. Ideally total installation should complete in an hour. But I'm not sure why it's taking very long time. I waited for 6 hours but still it didn't completed. So I tried to reinstall but faced the same issue 2nd time also.

My Laptop has below configuration:

```
RAM : 3 GB,
Free Hard Disk space on Destination drive: 33 GB,
Hard disk space assigned to UBUNTU while installing : 20 gb,
RAM assigned to UBUNTU while installing : 512 MB,
processor : Intel core i3 ,
OS: Genuine Windows 7 home (64 bit)
```

Any idea why it is happening? Or any suggestion for other version of Ubuntu which will be installed quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical servers problem or something like this. There is nothing wrong with your laptop/desktop. I've got a similar problem while trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 - [12.04 stuck during installation "Processing triggers for update-notifier-common"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139596/ubuntu-12-04-lts-stuck-on-installation-processing-triggers-for-update-notifier)

I think we need to wait a day (hope so) and let them fix the problem.

The only way to install Ubuntu now is to install it without having a internet connection active.

EDIT: Servers are on and everything is working perfectly.