# 12.04 stuck during installation "Processing triggers for update-notifier-common"

Tags: 12.04, installation, ubiquity

Everything is working fine till the end on installation where Ubuntu stuck on `ubuntu ubiquity: Processing triggers for update-notifier-common`.

Waited for more than 10 minutes and nothing, It stuck there.

Comment: Same issue here http://askubuntu.com/questions/353309/ubuntu-13-04-install-hangs-on-update-notifier-common# with 13.04, and just experienced the same with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.1 x64

Answer (score 1):

Can you try *removing* a network cable from the NIC before installing?

I encountered a similar problem with KVM and VirtualBox, and disabling a NIC works well.
(I don't understand why it works.)

Comment: NIC is not the problem.  I have the same issue with Ubuntu 12.10 installation.  I have no network cable attached.  The real reason for this is a broken Ubuntu package.